# Java D-heap implementation - infinite loop in deleteMin()

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, heap, infinite-loop

This is my first time asking a question on here, and I'll do my best not to break any formal procedures.

I'm trying to implement a small (and generic) D-ary heap ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap ) in Java, with the help of Mark Allen Weiss binary heap-code (http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~weiss/dsaajava2/code/BinaryHeap.java) and the code is almost done. However, there seems to be a problem when testing the heap; the test case goes into an infinte loop and I don't know why. I'd really appreciate help with resolving the issue.

Here's the relevant part of the test case ("heap" is a 3-heap):

```
@Test
public void testFindMin() {
    insert(3, 4, 6, 7, 1, 8, 2, 5);
    assertTrue(heap.size() == 8);
    assertTrue(heap.findMin() == 1);

    heap.makeEmpty();
    assertTrue(heap.isEmpty());

    insert(182, 64, 233, 906, 42, 678);
    assertTrue(heap.size() == 6);
    assertTrue(heap.findMin() == 42);

    heap.printHeap(); //The heap is 42, 64, 233, 906, 182, 678

    assertTrue(heap.deleteMin() == 42); //Here's where it gets stuck
    assertTrue(heap.size() == 5);
    assertTrue(heap.findMin() == 64);
}
```

And here's my code:

```
public class MyMiniHeap<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements MiniHeap<T> {

private int heapSize = 0;
private T[] heapArray;
private static final int DEFCAP = 10;
private int d;

public MyMiniHeap() {
    this(2, DEFCAP);
}

public MyMiniHeap(int children) {
    this(children, DEFCAP);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MyMiniHeap(int children, int capacity) {
    heapSize = 0;
    d = children;
    heapArray = (T[]) new Comparable[capacity + 1];
}


/**
 * Inserts an element into the heap, placing it correctly according
 * to heap properties.
 * 
 * @param element the element to insert.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the element to insert is null.
 */
public void insert(T element) {
    if (element == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot insert null");

    if (size() == heapArray.length - 1)
        doubleArraySize();

    int hole = ++heapSize;
    for( ; hole > 1 && element.compareTo(heapArray[getParent(hole)]) < 0; hole = getParent(hole)) {
        heapArray[hole] = heapArray[getParent(hole)];
    }
    heapArray[hole] = element;
}

/**
 * Deletes the smallest element in the heap.
 * 
 * @return the smallest element in the heap.
 * @throws IllegalStateException if the heap is empty.
 */
public T deleteMin() {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error: Empty heap");

    T minItem = findMin();
    heapArray[1] = heapArray[heapSize--];
    percolateDown(1);

    return minItem;
}

/**
 * Checks if the heap is empty or not.
 * 
 * @return true if the heap is empty, otherwise false.
 */
public T findMin() {
    if (isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalStateException("Error: Empty heap");

    return heapArray[1];
}

private void percolateDown(int hole) {
    int child = getChild(hole);
    int tempChild = getChild(hole);
    T tempElement = heapArray[hole];

    for( ; getChild(hole) <= size(); hole = child) {
        for(int i = 0; i < d && tempChild != size(); i++, tempChild++){
            if(heapArray[tempChild + 1].compareTo(heapArray[child]) < 0){
                child = tempChild + 1;
            }
        }

        if (heapArray[child].compareTo(tempElement) < 0)
            heapArray[hole] = heapArray[child];
        else
            break;
    }
    heapArray[hole] = tempElement;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void doubleArraySize() {
    T [] old = heapArray;
    heapArray = (T [])new Comparable[old.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < old.length; i++)
        heapArray[i] = old[i];
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}

public void makeEmpty() {       
    heapSize = 0;
}

public int size() {
    return heapSize;
}

/**
 * Finds the index of the first child for a given parent's index.
 * This method is normally private, but is used to test the
 * correctness of the heap.
 * 
 * @param parent the index of the parent.
 * @return an integer with the index of the parent's first child.
 */
public int getChild(int parent) {
    return d * (parent - 1) + 2;
}

/**
 * Finds the index of a parent for a given child's index.
 * This method is normally private, but is used to test
 * the correctness of the heap.
 * 
 * @param child the index of the child.
 * @return an integer with the child's parent's index.
 */
public int getParent(int child) {
    return (child - 2)/d + 1;
}

public void printHeap() {
    String output = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= size(); i++)
        output += heapArray[i].toString() + " ";
    System.out.println(output);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through line-by-line with a debugger?

Comment: I don't know what junit is showing if it cancel a test which runs to long but you can use `@Test(timeout=1000)` to let the test cancel if it takes to long.

Comment: @user614402: What do you mean? Infinite loops in Java are impossible! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949057    ... *(sorry couldn't resist ; )*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the bug is in this code:

```
for( ; getChild(hole) <= size(); hole = child) {
    for(int i = 0; i < d && tempChild != size(); i++, tempChild++){
        if(heapArray[tempChild + 1].compareTo(heapArray[child]) < 0){
            child = tempChild + 1;
        }
    }

    if (heapArray[child].compareTo(tempElement) < 0)
        heapArray[hole] = heapArray[child];
    else
        break;
}
```

Notice that in this loop, you only change the value of `child` in the nested `for` loop, but never elsewhere.  This means that if on some particular iteration none of the child nodes of the current node are less than the element at index `child`, then `child` is never reassigned and when you execute the loop step condition `hole = child` nothing will happen.  It seems like if you got unlucky with your heap structure this could easily be causing your infinite loop.

Similarly, in this loop you're never reassigning `tempChild`, so on each iteration `tempChild` will pick up where it left off on the previous iteration.  If on one of those iterations `tempChild` was equal to `size`, then the inner loop will never execute and each loop iteration will have no effect, again causing the infinite loop.

To fix this, I think you want to recompute `tempChild` and `index` on each iteration, as shown here:

```
for( ; getChild(hole) <= size(); hole = child) {
    child = getChild(hole);
    int tempChild = getChild(hole);

    for(int i = 0; i < d && tempChild != size(); i++, tempChild++){
        if(heapArray[tempChild + 1].compareTo(heapArray[child]) < 0){
            child = tempChild + 1;
        }
    }

    if (heapArray[child].compareTo(tempElement) < 0)
        heapArray[hole] = heapArray[child];
    else
        break;
}
```

I'm not sure if this is correct because I can't test it without access to the base class, but this seems like it's probably the culprit.  Try it out and let me know how it works.