# Is this a JVM bug or "expected behavior"?

Tags: java, jvm, compiler-optimization, integer-overflow

I noticed some unexpected behavior (unexpected relative to my personal expectations), and I'm wondering if something if there is a bug in the JVM or if perhaps this is a fringe case where I don't understand some of the details of what exactly is supposed to happen.  Suppose we had the following code in a main method by itself:

```
int i;
int count = 0;
for(i=0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i+=2){
  count++;
}
System.out.println(i++);
```

A naive expectation would be that this would print `Integer.MAX_VALUE-1`, the largest even representable `int`.  However, I believe integer arithmetic is supposed to "rollover" in Java, so adding 1 to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` should result in `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  Since `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is still less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, the loop would keep iterating through the negative even ints.  Eventually it would get back to 0, and this process should repeat as an infinite loop.

When I actually run this code, I get non-deterministic results.  The result that gets printed tends to be on the order of half a million, but the exact value varies.  So not only is the loop terminating when I believe it should be an infinite loop, but it seems to terminate randomly.  What's going on?

My guess is that this is either a bug in the JVM, or there is a lot of funky optimization going on that makes this expected behavior.  Which is it?

Comment: Is this all that's in your main method?

Comment: @Michael: Just checking there wasn't some funky threading going on. On my machine it's always printing out 2147483640, but that's still unexpected.

Comment: I tried it 3 times with different results between 300,000 and 500,000 - so looks like it is VM-specific (build 1.6.0_24-b07, 32bit linux)

Comment: The program never terminates on 32-bit Windows XP with HotSpot 1.6.0_24

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. bugs.sun.com would be the appropriate place to report it. (And yes, infinite loops should not terminate.)

Comment: Mine also never terminates. Java HotSpot 1.6.0_13-b03 @ WinXp 32 bit.

Comment: What JVM are you using? Sun JVM 1.6.0_23-b05 and 1.5.0_14-b03 both  loop forever.

Comment: Java never ceases to amaze me.  +1 to the OP and +1 to the answer linking to the Oracle/Sung bug(s). My latest favorite was this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949057 :)

Comment: +1 and bonus points for confusing/surprising Jon Skeet ;)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Known bug. Related to

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6196102

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6357214

and others.

I think they're considered low-priority to fix because they don't come up in the real world.

Answer (score 15):

This is bizarre. It certainly looks like a bug somewhere. I get the same results every time with the same code, but trivial changes to the code change the result. For example:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i+=2) {
      count++;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(i < Integer.MAX_VALUE);
  }
}
```

... always prints 2147483640 and true

whereas this:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i+=2) {
    }
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(i < Integer.MAX_VALUE);
  }
}
```

always prints -2147483648 and true.

Very, very weird.

(That's running an OpenJDK 1.6 VM on Linux.)

EDIT: Running OpenJDK 1.7 on Windows 7, I don't see the problem:

```
java version "1.7.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-ea-b78)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.0-b05, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `System.out.println(count);`

I wonder if there is optimization occurring because count is never read from.

**Edit** - another answer gave the link to bugs in Oracle's bug tracker. Drawing from that:

- [6196102](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6196102) in particular mentions that there is a canonicalization bug where `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is concerned.
- Java must be trying to optimize the loop because `count` is never read from.

However, this is unlikely to occur in practice, because:

- `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is an unlikely loop guard
- Usually loops do work that wouldn't allow this optimization in the first place

Comment: This makes my test runs consistent, at least.  So it is an optimization issue?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a loop optimizations as I observe the same result but IF I also print out `count` then the result changes.

I.e.

```
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for(i=0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i+=2){
      count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    System.out.println(i++);
```

Produces 2147483638 while the original code produces 457158 (or similar)

Answer (score 0):

```
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**working as expected. infinite loop**