# Erroneous for-loops in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, non-deterministic

I observed erroneous behaviour running the following java-code:

```
public class Prototype {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int start = Integer.MAX_VALUE/2;
    final int end = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    {
      long b = 0;
      for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        b++;
      }
      System.out.println(b);
    }
    {
      long b = 0;
      for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        b++;
      }
      System.out.println(b);
    }
  }
}
```

Both loops do exactly the same. Nevertheless, the second one outputs a non-deterministic erroneous value. I'm running the code on Linux using Version:

```
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

Sample Output:

```
1073741811
141312
```

Can you reproduce it? Is it a bug?

**Edit:** Strange

```
final int end = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1;
```

works fine.

Comment: There must be another error, as I get in both loops the value 1073741824

Comment: I have reproduced this bug on a MacBook running OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: @leifg: What system/JDK are you running on?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Linux with Sun Java 6u26 or OpenJDK 6b22.

Comment: run #1:
1073741811
76800

run #2:
1073741811
77824

run #3:
1073741811
60416

run #4:
1073741811
53248

Using jdk1.6.0_25 on Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: 1.6.0.24 on Windows 7, just wanted to point out taht even the first line seems not to be correct

Comment: Reproduced on MAC. Values are 1073741811 and 97280

Comment: You should try to determine whether it's a javac bug or a JITC bug.  Most likely a JITC bug, and it will go away if the range of the loops is reduced to a small number (eg, below 1000).

Comment: both reproduced same output 
1073741824
1073741824
Version, On Mac
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-383-11A511c)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-383, mixed mode)

Comment: Not sure it's exactly the right place, but I reported it to hotspot-dev-request@openjdk.java.net.

Comment: When reporting results, do a `java -version` and report the version displayed.

Comment: If I run it bug, but if I debug it then works fine. If a bug, then JITC bug.

Comment: can you post the .class file as well?

Comment: On Windows 7 64-bit, running 32-bit 1.6.0_26 Java both values end up the same: 1073741824
1073741824

Comment: I'm getting the same result as leifg and Maggie. Ran on RHEL 5.4 x64, JDK6u25 x64. $ java -version
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: Same as @Maggie on Windows 7 x64 running "1.6.0_35", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode).

Answer (score 13):

I'm able to reproduce it with the `.class` file produced by Eclipse, but not when compiling on the command line with `javac`.

The bytecode generated differs:

### `javac` output

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   lconst_0
   1:   lstore_3
   2:   ldc #2; //int 1073741823
   4:   istore  5
   6:   iload   5
   8:   ldc #3; //int 2147483647
   10:  if_icmpge   23
   13:  lload_3
   14:  lconst_1
   15:  ladd
   16:  lstore_3
   17:  iinc    5, 1
   20:  goto    6
   23:  getstatic   #4; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   26:  lload_3
   27:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(J)V
   30:  lconst_0
   31:  lstore_3
   32:  ldc #2; //int 1073741823
   34:  istore  5
   36:  iload   5
   38:  ldc #3; //int 2147483647
   40:  if_icmpge   53
   43:  lload_3
   44:  lconst_1
   45:  ladd
   46:  lstore_3
   47:  iinc    5, 1
   50:  goto    36
   53:  getstatic   #4; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   56:  lload_3
   57:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(J)V
   60:  return
```

For something easier to read, here is the Grimp output produced by [Soot](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/):

```
    java.lang.String[] r0;
    long l0, l2;
    int i1, i3;

    r0 := @parameter0;
    l0 = 0L;
    i1 = 1073741823;

 label0:
    if i1 >= 2147483647 goto label1;

    l0 = l0 + 1L;
    i1 = i1 + 1;
    goto label0;

 label1:
    java.lang.System.out.println(l0);
    l2 = 0L;
    i3 = 1073741823;

 label2:
    if i3 >= 2147483647 goto label3;

    l2 = l2 + 1L;
    i3 = i3 + 1;
    goto label2;

 label3:
    java.lang.System.out.println(l2);
    return;
```

### Eclipse compiler output

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   ldc #16; //int 1073741823
   2:   istore_1
   3:   ldc #17; //int 2147483647
   5:   istore_2
   6:   lconst_0
   7:   lstore_3
   8:   ldc #16; //int 1073741823
   10:  istore  5
   12:  goto    22
   15:  lload_3
   16:  lconst_1
   17:  ladd
   18:  lstore_3
   19:  iinc    5, 1
   22:  iload   5
   24:  ldc #17; //int 2147483647
   26:  if_icmplt   15
   29:  getstatic   #18; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   32:  lload_3
   33:  invokevirtual   #24; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(J)V
   36:  lconst_0
   37:  lstore_3
   38:  ldc #16; //int 1073741823
   40:  istore  5
   42:  goto    52
   45:  lload_3
   46:  lconst_1
   47:  ladd
   48:  lstore_3
   49:  iinc    5, 1
   52:  iload   5
   54:  ldc #17; //int 2147483647
   56:  if_icmplt   45
   59:  getstatic   #18; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   62:  lload_3
   63:  invokevirtual   #24; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(J)V
   66:  return
```

Grimp output:

```
    java.lang.String[] r0;
    int i0, i1, i3, i5;
    long l2, l4;

    r0 := @parameter0;
    i0 = 1073741823;
    i1 = 2147483647;
    l2 = 0L;
    i3 = 1073741823;
    goto label1;

 label0:
    l2 = l2 + 1L;
    i3 = i3 + 1;

 label1:
    if i3 < 2147483647 goto label0;

    java.lang.System.out.println(l2);
    l4 = 0L;
    i5 = 1073741823;
    goto label3;

 label2:
    l4 = l4 + 1L;
    i5 = i5 + 1;

 label3:
    if i5 < 2147483647 goto label2;

    java.lang.System.out.println(l4);
    return;
```

Interestingly, the `javac`-produced version uses `if_icmpge` as an exit condition (>= 2147483647) on an `int`, which shouldn't make sense (the equal does, but not the greater than). Both look correct, though, so I'd suspect a JVM bug.

Answer (score 6):

There are bugs that affect for loops specifically when the upper bound is close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183468/is-this-a-jvm-bug-or-expected-behavior).

Comment: The Eclipse-generated bytecode seems to work just fine with `end = Integer.MAX_VALUE-1`, so it seems specific to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` indeed.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Java gurus this is [bug 5091921](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5091921), fixed in JDK7 but not planned for a fix in JDK6.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible it is the erroneous loop unrolling in HotSpot in 64-bit server VM. Try running the code with either `-client` or `+XX:-AggressiveOpts`.